# Weird behaviour when seeding Java Random

Tags: java, random

The following code should create two Random objects with identical seeds:

```
System.out.println("System time before: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
Random r1 = new Random();
Random r2 = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("System time after: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

System.out.println("r1: " + r1.nextInt());
System.out.println("r2: " + r2.nextInt());
```

The seeds should be identical since `System.currentTimeMillis()` did not change before and after creating the two objects as shown in the output:

```
System time before: 1331889186449
System time after: 1331889186449
r1: -1836225474
r2: 2070673752
```

From the docs, the constructor without any arguments is simply:

```
public Random() { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }
```

So what gives? Can anyone explain why the two generators return different outputs when they should have the same seed?

Comment: In most IDEs you can do `<ctrl>+<click>` to see the source of a method.

Comment: "The seeds should be identical since `System.currentTimeMillis()` did not change before and after creating the two objects" - There is no guarantee that that is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using java.util.Random, this is the default no-args constructor I see - now it might depend on the version of JDK you are using (this code seems to be used for sun JDK 6 & 7 at least):

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

And just to confirm it, here is a code to check if the seeds are identical:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println("System time before: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    Random r1 = new Random();
    Random r2 = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("System time after: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

    Field seed = Random.class.getDeclaredField("seed");
    seed.setAccessible(true);
    AtomicLong seed1 = (AtomicLong) seed.get(r1);
    AtomicLong seed2 = (AtomicLong) seed.get(r2);

    System.out.println("seed1 = " + seed1);
    System.out.println("seed2 = " + seed2);
}
```

Comment: My quick google search brought up [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) - where did you find that?

Comment: @Andrew that's from Java 1.4.2

Comment: The lesson to take away from this is too never depend on the internal definition of a class or method for your own logic.

Comment: Teach me not to use my IDE... so Eclipse is giving me `public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }`which is what @Roman posted below. I wonder why this is different to your answer?

Comment: @Andrew because you are probably using a different JDK... He is on Max OS X, I am on Windows, not sure what the differences are.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the default constructor does what you say it does (i.e., `public Random { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }` The java documentation just says that it is initialising the class with a value that is likely be different on each invocation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29). Looking in a header in my implementation of `Random` (Mac OS X)

```
public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

> the two generators return different outputs when they should have the same seed?

they do? it looks to me that only one of your generators is getting the millis seed...