# Does java.util.Random implementation differ between JREs or platforms?

Tags: java, random

The `next` method of `java.util.Random`, when I view source in Eclipse, is essentially:

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
```

How can I determine if different JDKs or JVMs will implement `next` in a different way or with different constants?

I have already come across different no-argument constructors in  [Weird behaviour when seeding Java Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734606/weird-behaviour-when-seeding-java-random). I want to know if a similar thing might occur with the `next` method. Where can I find the source to different implementations?

Comment: If it absolutely has to be the same, I would take a copy of the code and use that instead. Although the documentation suggests this shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javadoc for `Random.next()` explicitly states which algorithm is used to generate the next number.

It is theoretically possible that a different JVM might use a different algorithm, but this is unlikely, especially if you restrict yourself to JVM' that are based on the Sun / Oracle libraries.

---

> Does that documentation necessarily apply to all JDKs?

You'd need to check to be sure, but probably yes.  This is the kind of thing that Sun / Oracle are unlikely to change because of the potential for breaking lots of existing Java applications and test suites written over that last 15 or so years.

Here are some facts:

- the javadoc for Java 1.3.1 through Java 1.7 (*) contains the exact same specification for this method,
- an implementation is only permitted to use the trademark "Java" if it conforms to the specification
- most (if not all) Java(TM) implementations use class libraries that are derived from the Oracle / Sun source code,
- developers would notice that a different algorithm was used ... and complain loudly.

So the likelihood of a Java(TM) implementation using a different algorithm is pretty small.

(* I couldn't find the Java 1.1 javadocs online, but I *expect* that they will say the same thing.)

Comment: I thought the contract might be a more general 'generates a random number...' and therefore changes to the implementation would theoretically be allowed without breaking anything.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I determine if different JDKs or JVMs will implement next in a different way or with different constants?

By using the same seed in a program on different JVMs and seeing if you get the same sequence, as the sequence is deterministic for a given seed.

I'm not sure JDKs are allowed to use a different algorithm, though, as the [documentation for `next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) says:

> The method `next` is implemented by class `Random` by atomically updating the seed to
>
> `(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)`
>
> and returning
>
> `(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits)).`
>
> This is a linear congruential pseudorandom number generator, as defined by D. H. Lehmer and described by Donald E. Knuth in *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 3: *Seminumerical Algorithms*, section 3.2.1.

...which seems to set a specific contract, although just before that it says

> The general contract of `next` is that it returns an `int` value and if the argument `bits` is between `1` and `32` (inclusive), then that many low-order bits of the returned value will be (approximately) independently chosen bit values, each of which is (approximately) equally likely to be `0` or `1`.

...so perhaps that's allowing wiggle room on the algorithm.

> Where can I find the source to different implementations?

If they're open source, presumably you can find the implementation in the project's repo. If they're closed, well...

Comment: Does that documentation necessarily apply to all JDKs?

Comment: @ Andrew: The linked documentation is the official documentation for Java 7 SE, not a specific JDK. So yes, it applies to all conformant JDKs. A JDK that varies from the official documentation is non-conformant.